# Java - continues adding value on integer

Tags: java, integer, addition

im having a little problem about my codes

```
public class ex{
public static void main(String[] args) {
int sum,int a = 1,int b = 2;
int c = 1,int d = 2;

if (a<b) {
    sum = sum+1;
}
if (c<b) {
    sum = sum+1;    
}
System.out.println("output :"+sum); 
}
}
```

I wanted to add a value of 1 in the `int sum` if the conditions are met. but its not compiling

the output should be like this:

```
output: 2
```

Comment: You are already doing it. So what is the problem ?

Comment: where and how do you set the startvalue of sum?

Comment: That doesn't seem to compile.. http://ideone.com/rYzIf5

Comment: The code does not compile.

Comment: Except for the fact that the code you're showing is uncompilable, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

First things first.. If you are a beginner to Java, this is an advise for you to learn well about the syntax of Java declaration, initialization and usage.

Declaration:
If you want to declare variables separately, you have to do it as below:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

If you want to declare multiple variables in a single line, you have to do it as below:

```
int a,b,c;
```

Initialization:
If you want to initialize multiple variables in a single line, do it as below:

```
int a=0, b=4, c=3;
```

Usage:
Important thing you would like to learn here is - you can always declare 'n' number of variables without initialization.. but if you want to use any of them, they must be initialized at least once before you use them. Using them also includes even to print them.

If you won't follow any of the above mentioned points, you must get a compilation error.

Here is the code you must follow:

```
public class ex{
public static void main(String[] args) {
int sum = 0 , a = 1, b = 2;
int c = 1, d = 2;

if (a < b) {
    sum = sum + 1;
}
if (c < b) {
    sum = sum + 1;    
}
System.out.println("output :"+sum); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestExample {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int sum = 0 ;
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 1;
        int d = 2;

        if (a<b) {
            sum = sum+1;
        }
        if (c<b) {
            sum = sum+1;    
        }
        System.out.println("output :"+sum);
    }

}
```

declaration of variable is wrong you should not declare your variable like `int a,int b= 10`
avoid declaration  of variable on same line.

your code gives compilation error try this one it will give output as your expectation

Comment: Code only answers should be avoided, you should also **explain** what you propose, and why.  a mere "try this, it works" doesn't cut it.

Comment: Probably the initialization of the ints isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare variables on the same line like this, even when it's compilable. It compacts your code in a way that makes it difficult to understand, especially when you name them `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`.

```
int sum = 0;
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 1;
int d = 2;
```

Change your declaration of variables to that and the rest of the code will run fine. But I would recommend reading some basic Java tutorials so you understand how to write code that compiles. I would also suggest using an IDE so these kinds of errors are flagged while you write your code.

IDEOne (with compilation errors): http://ideone.com/rYzIf5 
 
IDEOne (without compilation errors): http://ideone.com/rYzIf5

Comment: i did declare the int like this but it wont compile, so i try something like what i post above.

Comment: My friend it won't compile anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
int sum = 0,a = 1,b = 2;
int c = 1, d = 2;

if (a<b) {
    sum++;
}
if (c<b) {
    sum++;    
}

System.out.println("output :"+sum);
```